# sorting the array and finding repeated numbers

Tags: java, arrays

```
package array;

import java.util.Arrays;

public class learning_program1 {

    public static void main(String[] args) {

        int arr[]= {1,2,3,4,10,20,30,6,6,5,4,5,5,2};

        Arrays.sort(arr);
        for(int i = 0; i < arr.length; i++) 
        {   
            int count =0;
            int flag=0;
            for(int j=i+1; j<arr.length; j++)
            {
                while(arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    j++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;
            }
            if(flag==1)
            {
                System.out.println("the repeated values " + arr[i] + " is " +count);
            }


        }

    }
}
```

Output:

the repeated values 2 is 1

the repeated values 4 is 1

the repeated values 5 is 2

the repeated values 5 is 1

the repeated values 6 is 1

my question is 
i am getting the output but 5 is repeating twice

Comment: You can tackle this situation better by using a `Map` or a `HashMap`. Keep the digit in the array as a key inside `Map` or `HashMap` and its count as value.

Comment: yep, i tired by                                                                         
            while(arr[i] == arr[j])
                {
                    count++;
                    j++;
                    flag=1;
                }
                break;     i=j;(assinging duplicate values of last find and assign to i)    but i am not getting the proper output

Comment: There is no need to sort the input

Comment: The current answers show good ways of tackling this problem, but you might find them a bit advanced if you are only just beginning to learn Java. You can still carry on with your solution using only arrays. Your error is in your inner for/while loop. You only need one loop there. Think carefully about the terminating condition. It may help if you do this manually first (using pen and paper) to see exactly what you need to do.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use `Stream`. First you have to group all elements in the given `arr` by it's value and counting them. Then, filter elements that appears more than once.

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> findDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Long> map = Arrays.stream(arr)
                                   .boxed()
                                   .collect(Collectors.groupingBy(Function.identity(), Collectors.counting()));

    Map<Integer, Integer> res = new TreeMap<>();

    map.entrySet().stream()
       .filter(entry -> entry.getValue() > 1)
       .forEach(entry -> res.put(entry.getKey(), entry.getValue().intValue() - 1));

    return res;
}
```

In this case, your client code will be look like this:

```
int arr[] = { 1, 2, 3, 4, 10, 20, 30, 6, 6, 5, 4, 5, 5, 2 };
Map<Integer, Integer> map = findDuplicates(arr);
map.forEach((key, count) -> System.out.println("the repeated values " + key + " is " + count));
```

*Outputs:*

```
the repeated values 2 is 1
the repeated values 4 is 1
the repeated values 5 is 2
the repeated values 6 is 1
```

**P.S.**
In case you hesitate to use `Stream`, the it is easy to do it without it, just rely on `Set` and `Map`:

```
public static Map<Integer, Integer> findDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    Set<Integer> values = new HashSet<>();
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new TreeMap<>();

    for (int val : arr)
        if (!values.add(val))
            map.put(val, map.getOrDefault(val, 0) + 1);

    return map;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

You should change your method used to find duplicates. It's better to use HashMap. Try to implement it like this:

```
Map<Integer, Integer> findDuplicates(int[] arr) {
    Map<Integer, Integer> map = new HashMap<>();
    for(int i: arr) {
        if(map.containsKey(i)) {
            map.put(i, map.get(i)+1);
        } else {
            map.put(i, 1);
        }
    }

    return map;
}
```

Then just iterate through all keys in the map and check how many elements it has.

If you still want to use your code, then you can use another variable to keep list of numbers which where already processed. Your code checks 5 two times:

1. 5, 4, 5, 5
2. 4, 5, 5

So the output looks like it looks

Comment: Of course we can. Just use your code but just be sure that you don't check the same numbers several times. You can also change your array to `List` and use `Collections` class. Something like this `if (Collections.frequency(iList, elem) > 1) {...}` There are many different solutions to this problem, but HashMap is very simple and efficient.